# Running Model in Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

Having a lot of trouble trying to run a model I built in ModelBuilder in Python. What is the proper way to do this? I'm adding the toolbox then running the model. Seems easy enough but I'm getting an error saying the Tool is not valid.

Ultimately, I read that running models in Python is going to be faster than if I did it in arcGiS Pro. If that is not the case then this is all pointless. Would love some additional input.

Utilizing this article here: support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012716

```
import arcpy    
toolbox = arcpy.AddToolbox(r"C:\Users\dsser\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject1\Toolbox.tbx")
toolbox.ModelDS()
print("Script finished")
```

Comment: You need to ImportToolbox.

Comment: Negative. Still not working. I am pulling straight from this article: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012716

Comment: That should be mentioned in your question body.  In any event I suspect you are omitting your tool's alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used AddToolbox as a way of running a model in python, even their [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/addtoolbox.htm) suggests using ImportToolbox!

Have a look [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/adding-and-removing-toolboxes.htm) and take note of the alias as suggested by @Polygeo.